# PubSub async publishing

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I wanted to make sure (haven't found it anywhere in the documentation), If I am using PubSub async publishing as part of my service handling request logic (Python Django) -

```
*handling request*
publish async PubSub messages
*handling request*
returning response
```

Is it guaranteed that the async PubSub publisher won't delay my response to that specific request? when does it exactly publish the events?

Thanks

Comment: On which platform/service run your code?

Comment: GCP. the service handles requests, I am trying to figure out if PubSub waits until the handling of the request is done and then publishes the event that was queued?

Comment: GCP is not enough detail. Which service on GCP? The behavior of service can have side effect on the async publish